# Can I use Command design pattern for operations with different number of parameters and different return types?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I work on a project which has many different operations like file operations, registry operations, process operations, finding minimum requirements etc. 
All these classes are getting injected into one class , thereby, making it's coupling very high.
I came across command pattern which seemed like a good idea for this project.
But my operations take different parameters and have different return types. Command pattern had only one execute method with void as return type.
Is there a way I can use this pattern for this project to reduce coupling or should I use some other design pattern?

Comment: Forget design patterns for now. Do it without any patterns, not the whole project but one complete part of it, then post your code on the CodeReview site and ask what patterns would be ideal in such a case. Right now we do not have enough information to suggest a pattern.

Comment: Same here, you should address the *All these classes are getting injected into one class* part to begin with, before thinking about using a pattern.

Comment: You could use command patterns. Even though the execute does not (ideally) take any parameters, there could be members in the command to setup the context before execution (and steps after to build/get the return). Also commands could be in an inheritance hierarcy as well, where related commands could use the same start setup (which could be exploited for generic file operations or process operations in your case)